# how to change the type of the columns in a given dataframe using pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

how to create a function to change the dtypes of columns in a dataframe in streamlit where the user select the type that he want to convert the selected column to it?

I create a function  that take a dataframe as argument than display in a dropdown list the types that can the user choose from it.

the problem is that when the user select the new type and the system print `df.info()` the selected column still having the old type.

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

def transform(df):
    types = {'-':None
           ,'Boolean': '?'
           ,'Byte': 'b'
           ,'Integer':'i'
           ,'Floating point': 'f' 
           ,'Date Time': 'M'
           ,'Time': 'm'
           ,'Unicode String':'U'
           ,'Object': 'O'}
    new_types = {}
    expander_types = st.beta_expander('Convert Data Types')
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        txt = 'Convert {} from {} to:'.format(col, df[col].dtypes)
        expander_types.markdown(txt, unsafe_allow_html=True)
        new_types[i] = expander_types.selectbox('Field to be converted:',[*types],index=0,key=i)
    st.text(" \n") #break line
    btn1 = st.button('Get CSV')
    if btn1:
        download_file(df, types, new_types, "csv")
        print("transform",df.info())
```

where is the error in my function ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas can convert data in existing columns to different datatypes. For most string, integer, float, or boolean data, use [pd.convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) and for datetime use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime). If you need a custom output that isn't converting datatypes (like time instead of datetime), you can use [df.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) with a function that inputs the data in its original form and outputs the data in the form you desire.

Comment: yes i was trying to convert a column to `time`   so how to make this conversion ??

Comment: You can make a function that inputs the data in the format you want and output the time, possibly using [`time.time()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-time-time-method/). This can then be used with df.apply to create a new column.

Comment: `..to create a new column` or assign to the existing column.

Comment: pd.to_datetime() ??? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html